# How to display a number of posts based on a Advanced Custom Field (ACF)

Tags: plugins, query-posts, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following code working fine in my theme:

```
<!-- Modify query object -->
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&post_type=news'); ?>

<!-- Start the Loop -->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                  the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
            ?>
            <p>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>

<!-- Stop The Loop -->
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 <?php endif; ?>

<!-- Reset the Loop. -->
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
```

I need to the number of posts to be based on a custom field.

I am not sure how to go about doing this.

My set-up:
Page template: front-page.php

Homepage: set to the 'home' Page

Custom field: Custom field is in the 'Home' Page. I am using ACF plugin for custom fields

Thanks

UPDATE:
- screenshots included of my setup

[image: Edit screen of the 'Home' Page]
[image: Site settings screen]
[image: Custom field setup using ACF plugin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to my question using the ACF plugin **get_field** function (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) to retrieve the value of the custom field, save it as a variable and then use it as part of the query_post parameters:

```
<!-- Modify query object -->
<?php
$num_news = get_field("number_news", 523); // number of news items to feature
query_posts('showposts='.$num_news.'&post_type=news'); 
?>
... rest of the code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**First: [Don't use query_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755)**

Next you need to add a custom field called 'posts_per_page' to your page.

Finally put this in your function.php while removing the query_posts call from your code.

```
function limit_home_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Get the custom field ...
        $posts_per_page = intval(get_field('number_of_latest_news_items_to_promote_on_homepage'));
        // then get '$posts_per_page' posts...
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $posts_per_page );
        // ...of type 'news'
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'news' ) );
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_home_query', 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already have the custom field setup. My problem how do I use the field to control the number of posts in my query (point taken about not using query_posts but can we stick with it for now).

Comment: The code above should do everything you want. Please clarify what doesn't work for you.

Comment: I won't be able to try the code till tonight but not sure where your code should go in relation to mine (in place of it? after it ? before it?). Also, I have other similar loops in the same template page (hence the rewind_posts), is this a problem?

Comment: Add the other loops to your question as this might be relevant. Also I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, other loop exactly the same but pulling from another post type or a specific category but generally the same in terms of structure (again I won't be able to try code till tonight but I appropriate your help)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found a better way of doing what I needed (see my accepted answer)